# Merging records with SQL, with some rules

Tags: sql, merge, duplicates, concatenation

I have a table with 4 records:

```
NAME    INSTRUMENT    BOOLEAN 1  BOOLEAN 2
Bob     Organ         TRUE       FALSE
Thomas  Violin        FALSE      FALSE
Bob     Piano         FALSE      TRUE
```

I want to merge records with same "NAME", in order to get  :

```
Bob     Organ Piano   TRUE       TRUE
Thomas  Violin        FALSE      FALSE
```

What's the rule that I want when merging ?

- "text fields" are just concatenated    (example : Organ + Piano ==> "Organ Piano")
- "boolean fields" are merged with a LOGICAL OR   (example : TRUE or FALSE = TRUE)

My questions :

1) I will choose which software to use in regard to the ability to do this!   Database with SQL queries (SQLite, MySQL or even Access)   or Excel ?

2) If the best solution is a database,   what's the SQL query to do that ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I tried Excel's duplicates deletion tool,  but it's not powerful enough to do this...

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... more advanced features are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My choes and SQLServer2005+

```
SELECT a.NAME AS NAME,(
SELECT ISNULL(b.INSTRUMENT, '')+ ' '
FROM dbo.COExample b WHERE b.NAME=a.NAME
FOR XML PATH('')) AS INSTRUMENT, MAX(CAST(BOOLEAN1 AS int)) AS BOOLEAN1, MAX(CAST(BOOLEAN2 AS int)) AS BOOLEAN2
FROM dbo.COExample a
GROUP BY a.NAME
```

Example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b4b9/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL Server 2005 or higher, below is a set of T-SQL statements that will illustrate your example above (using a combox of a cross apply and case statements):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COExample](
   [NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
   [INSTRUMENT] [varchar](50) NULL,
   [BOOLEAN1] [bit] NULL,
   [BOOLEAN2] [bit] NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.COExample VALUES('Bob','Organ',1,0);
INSERT INTO dbo.COExample VALUES('Thomas','Violin',0,0);
INSERT INTO dbo.COExample VALUES('Bob','Piano',0,1);

SELECT DISTINCT c.NAME, RTRIM(CombInstruments.combinstruments) AS 'INSTRUMENTS'
,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.COExample b1 WHERE b1.NAME = c.NAME AND b1.BOOLEAN1 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'BOOLEAN1'
,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.COExample b2 WHERE b2.NAME = c.NAME AND b2.BOOLEAN2 = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'BOOLEAN2'
FROM dbo.COExample c

CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT ISNULL(c2.INSTRUMENT,'') + ' '
   FROM dbo.COExample c2
   WHERE c2.NAME = c.NAME
   ORDER BY c2.INSTRUMENT FOR XML PATH('')
) CombInstruments(combinstruments)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test this.
Where is the function that DELETES the duplicate record ?
Do you think it's possible to have a solution with deletion of the duplicate record ?

Comment: Well, now realize that this doesn't actually delete anything, it just rolls it up to the output that you were after. The premise here is that the 2 records with the name Bob are truly not duplicates. They have the same name value of 'Bob', but each record stores different data (one with an organ and the other with a violin). If you want to merge these records into one, that would take additional processing and I would question what exactly is your user experince that you're trying to accomplish?